# npm not recongnizing my virtual environment

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, flask, npm

Im making a react app with flask as backend and im following [this article](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-create-a-react--flask-project) guide, so in this article he adds a custom `npm` script to start `flask` app. I did the exact same thing and did `npm run start-api` but im getting the following error -

```
> weather-app@0.1.0 start-api C:\Users\Kakshipth\Documents\coding\webdev\weather-app
> cd api && venv/bin/flask run --no-debugger

'venv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! weather-app@0.1.0 start-api: `cd api && venv/bin/flask run --no-debugger`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the weather-app@0.1.0 start-api script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kakshipth\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-31T05_01_09_393Z-debug.log
```

Yes, i double checked if the name of my virtual environment is correct, and it is correct.

here is my `package.json` file where i specified the script -

```
{
  "name": "weather-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "materialize-css": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "venv": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start-api": "cd api && venv/bin/flask run --no-debugger",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ],
    "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: is it a windows path thing? does `venv\\bin\\flask` make any difference?

Comment: thanks, but thats not the solution, error log now says `cannot find the path` so the earlier format was correct

Comment: I think it's trying to run `venv` in `venv/bin/flask` as `/` is an argument in a windows prompt (`dir/a/p` is a valid command). change `venv` to `blah` and you should see the binary name change

Comment: so then what's in `C:\Users\Kakshipth\Documents\coding\webdev\weather-app\api\venv\bin\`

Comment: @Matt i changed `venv` to `blah` in `package.json`, yes the error output did change(obv), and to answers to 2nd question, `venv/bin` has `flask` installed in it

Answer (score 0):

in order to run within virtual environment, you need to [`activate`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#activators) the virtual environment first.

try executing the npm script after you activated the virtual environment

```sh
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ npm run start-api
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running on windows, it doesn't recognize the path you have given in the `package.json` file, edit the `"scripts"` as:

```
"start-api": "cd api && venv\\bin\\flask run --no-debugger",
```

Then try activating the virutal environment and running npm script.

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ npm run start-api
```

Answer (score 0):

I also followed the same example and the answer is here: [Integration of React framework and Flask framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936760/integration-of-react-framework-and-flask-framework)

You need to run both commands concurrently.

I installed [concurrently](https://yarnpkg.com/package/concurrently#usage) with `yarn` then updated the command in the `package.json` to use both commands according to the `concurrently` docs, eg.

```
"start": "concurrently \"command1 arg\" \"command2 arg\""
```